# Sci-fi movie about robots killing sad people

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

Astronauts come (back?) to a city ruled by robots. Most people are dead.
When people get sad the robots detect it and kill.
The robots shows a happy or sad smiley corresponding to their analysis of the person being checked.

I think the dead people were used as fertilizer for the food production.
The robots got their instructions wrong trying to create happiness.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you watch this film, and when do you think it was made? Also, was it in black & white or in colour?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Please [read our Story ID tips](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/62709) to see if it jogs loose anything else that could be used to identify your story.

Comment: That is pretty much the plot of *Doctor Who* Series 10, "Smile", but it's likely it was used before.

Comment: Whilst the accepted answer is correct, anyone searching on this title may also be looking for a 1980s Doctor Who series, [The Happiness Patrol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Happiness_Patrol).  People who are visibly sad are executed by [Kandyman](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Kandyman), a psychopathic robot obsessed with confectionery. (Turned an answer into a comment instead, since we have a correct answer.)

Comment: @Graham perfectly fine to leave it as an answer, as you said; other people will come here and may not be looking for the same one as op.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Doctor Who Season 10 episode 2 "Smile"

> The Doctor brings Bill to a future human colony, where cute EmojiBots work as willing servants and make sure everybody's happy, but if they're not happy, they're harvested.

[image: robots]

Comment: Exactly!! Thankyou Oni!!

Comment: though the suggestion was that it was a movie

Comment: So a bit like removing downvotes and flagging "mean" comments.

Comment: That image looks so much like that scene in Psycho Pass which does something similar.

Comment: @pipe I don't see any similarity.